# How to stop Autosave after 30 mins or so?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, kill-process, autosave

I am working on autosaving a form using jQuery. This form will keep saving data every 1 min. However, I don't want to spam the database if the user has that browser open for one day. So I want to kill the autosave option if there is no change or if the browser has been open for 30 min.

Anyway I can kill this autosave function?

```
$("form input").on("input propertychange change", function() {

  var start = $.now();

  setTimeout(autoSaveForm(start), 10000);
});

function autoSaveForm(start) {
  var uuid = $("#uuid").html();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "trailers/" + uuid + "/save-draft",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function() {
    }
  });

  if ($.now() - start <= 600000) {
    setTimeout(autoSaveForm(start), 60000);
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can cancel a timeout with [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout).

Also, you will need to setup a timestamp variable, so your `autoSaveForm` will check if 30 min have not passed since that timestamp and it can proceed with saving the form. If the time has passed simply stop execution with `return` and the next `setTimeout` will not be set.

Even better would be to change your approach, and only save data after any change was made to your form. You can do that with listening `keyup` and `change` events on your form inputs. If you fear that your auto-save function will be fired too often, you should make it not run more often than at least several seconds for example. That is done with a throttle function, example of which is in an underscore library: [`_.throttle`](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

And here's some code: http://jsfiddle.net/yuraji/4pnbr4bd/ - it updates only on user input and never more often that 1 second.

Comment: Thanks! My form is a nested and nested form. Form change function is not reacting to changes in nested fields. I have updated my code according to your instruction. Can you take a look?

Comment: Note, that may probably confuse someone who comes back to the form in an hour. Something else you can do is update the timestamp on a user action.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code and it is still not working. It keeps sending ajax request to the server non-stop without delay....Can you take a look?

Comment: That is because your current code sets a new `setTimeout` on _every_ change, and then every of those keep calling themselves endlessly. You might just `throttle` your function. Something like `autoSaveForm = _.throttle(autoSaveForm, 1000)`, which will at least make sure it doesn't run too often.